# How can I access the original files (the lowerdir) of an overlay mounted on the same location as the lowerdir?

Tags: linux, mount, fedora, overlay

The situation that I've found myself in is that I'm having to run Fedora Linux from a semi-read-only location. I can make edits to the file system, placing files and such, but all is lost on reboot, and as an added hassle, I cannot easily increase the available storage space either. I do have access to some writable media though, so I thought I'd do this:

```
sudo mount --bind /usr /home/username/Store/Orig/usr
sudo mount -t overlay ovl_usr -o lowerdir=/usr,upperdir=/home/username/Store/usr,workdir=/home/username/Store/Work/usr /usr
```

The second line works okay, it's the first line that isn't working. What it's meant to do is give me non-overlaid access to the original contents of `/usr`. I'd expect that since the bind mount is created before the overlay is mounted on `/usr`, `/home/username/Store/Orig/usr` would still see the old contents. But no, `/home/username/Store/Orig/usr` shows the overlaid files, just like `/usr`.

Is there a way to access the original contents of `/usr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're experiencing a "shared" behavior, while you need "private". See [`man 8 mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> The shared subtrees operations.
>   Since Linux 2.6.15 it is possible to mark a mount and its submounts as shared, private, slave or unbindable. A shared mount provides ability to create mirrors of that mount such that mounts and umounts within any of the mirrors propagate to the other mirror. […] A private mount carries no propagation abilities. […]

Solution: after `mount --bind …` and before `mount -t overlay …` invoke:

```
sudo mount --make-private /home/username/Store/Orig/usr
```

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can. So you're saying that because the bind mount is shared, the mount on the original location is visible on the new location as well? And that therefore making the bind mount private would solve the problem?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes.

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work - thanks! One thing that wasn't part of the exact question, but that you might have wanted to point out nonetheless, is that one can run into issues if the ownership and permissions of the original and new /usr differ. I'm now toiling around with chown and chmod to fix everything. If only I had just had it set up correctly from the outset...